# cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind') / it seems that you may have accidentally written "greet" instead of "green"

Tags: error-handling, p5.js

Errors constantly occur in the process of using "p5.js".

I want to make a new work by combining the following two codes. The two codes and the screen when they were executed are as follows.

https://editor.p5js.org/jymkomu0304/sketches/elOhIqxv3
https://editor.p5js.org/jymkomu0304/sketches/YU6rNV2VK

So I tried combining the two codes.

https://editor.p5js.org/jymkomu0304/sketches/FMmUaaRsd

However, an error occurs.

1. If I put greet in input.changed(),
   -> "it seems that you may have accidentally written "greet" instead of "green""
2. If I put another word(that I made, I don't know what to put),
   -> "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')"

I'm not sure what these sentences mean. I am not good at English.

The finished work I want is as follows. This is what I made by editing the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bThmz.jpg)

There are countless squares listed, and in between, the words entered by the user are written down. The square containing the word is white, and the word is colored randomly like the rest of the squares. (The user can determine "hue" by using "slider". But "Saturation" and "Brightness" are random.) In addition, the user may adjust the size of the rectangle (the number of squares shown on the screen) using another slider.

I want to set the size of the square to fit the size of the word, but I don't know how. I also don't know how to arrange words between squares.

I'd really appreciate your help. I have to hand in my assignment before 8 p.m. U.S. time (3 hours left). I'm really desperate. This is my last hope.

Comment: This is because `greet` is not defined in the scope when you call `input.changed()`. `greet` is defined inside `drawGrids`, so when you put it in as a parameter of `changed()`, it is unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You had many errors in the code, but I think i managed to fix them:

```
var input, button, greeting, sslider, aslider;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  var stepY = 20; //not sure what this value should be
  input = createInput();
  input.position(30, 30);
  input.changed(greet);
  button = createButton('submit');
  button.position(input.x + input.width, 30);
  button.mousePressed(greet);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(stepY);
  colorMode(HSB);
  colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100);

  sslider = createSlider(10, 100, 50, 1);
  sslider.position(30, 60);
  sslider.changed( drawGrids );
  aslider = createSlider(0, 360, 180, 1);
  aslider.position(30, 90);
  aslider.changed( drawGrids);
}
  
function drawGrids() {
  background(255);
  let a = aslider.value();
  let maxGrids = sslider.value();
  let stepX = width/maxGrids*2;
  let stepY = height/maxGrids;
  for (let y=0; y<height; y+=stepY) {
    for (let x=0; x<width; x+=stepX) {
      let c = color(a, random(30, 100), random(30, 100));  
      fill(c);
      noStroke();
      rect(x,y,stepX,stepY);
    }
  }
}
  
function greet() {
  let name = input.value();
  input.value('');
  for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
    fill(i, random(30,100), random(30, 100));
    text(name, random(width), random(height));
  }
}
```